# mysql - how aright get count rows and max count in table?

Tags: mysql

Structure tables on **[sqlfile.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19)**

Query:

```
SELECT 
ei.ItemIdn as ItemIdn,
ei.UserIdn as UserIdn,
ifnull(cb.BestPrice,0) as BestPrice,
cv.CountShow as CountShow,
cb.CountBids as CountBids,
ifnull(r.CountReactivation,0) as CountReactivation

FROM items ei

left join (
  SELECT count(*) as CountShow, ItemIdn 
  FROM CountViewes 
  WHERE ItemIdn = ItemIdn) as cv on cv.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

left join (
  SELECT count(*) as CountBids, Max(Bid) as BestPrice, ItemIdn 
  FROM CountBids 
  WHERE ItemIdn = ItemIdn) as cb on cb.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

left join (SELECT count(*) as CountReactivation, ItemIdn 
           FROM Reactivation 
           WHERE ItemIdn = ItemIdn) as r on r.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

WHERE ei.UserIdn = '0000' 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

Problem: if i use `left join` i get only one row(see [**sqlfiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19/3)), but table `items` have 4 rows

Tell me please how aright get counts rows and max values with `left join` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by doing an aggregation inside the subquery:

```
left join (SELECT ItemIdn, count(*) as CountBids, Max(Bid) as BestPrice
           FROM CountBids
           GROUP BY ItemIdn
          ) cb
          on cb.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn
```

EDIT:

You need to replace the `ItemIdn = ItemIdn` in each of the subqueries with `group by ItemIdn`.  You also need to remove the `count()` from the outer query:

```
SELECT 
    ei.ItemIdn as ItemIdn,
    ei.UserIdn as UserIdn,
    ifnull(cb.BestPrice,0) as BestPrice,
    cv.CountShow as CountShow,
    cb.CountBids as CountBids,
    ifnull(r.CountReactivation,0) as CountReactivation

FROM items ei

    left join (
      SELECT count(*) as CountShow, ItemIdn 
      FROM CountViewes 
      group by ItemIdn) as cv on cv.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

    left join (
      SELECT count(*) as CountBids, Max(Bid) as BestPrice, ItemIdn 
      FROM CountBids  cb
      group by ItemIdn ) as cb on cb.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

    left join (SELECT count(*) as CountReactivation, ItemIdn 
               FROM Reactivation
               group by ItemIdn) as r on r.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

WHERE ei.UserIdn = '0000' ;
```

If you do intend an aggregation at the outer level, then use `sum()`, not `count()`.

Comment: i can not make aright - please see **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19/3)** P.S.: i edit question.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SELECT 
    ei.DateStart as DateStart,
    ei.DateEnd as DateEnd,
    ei.ItemIdn as ItemIdn,
    ei.Title as Title,
    ei.AuctionMinCost as AuctionMinCost,
    ei.Priority as Priority,
    ei.PriceBuyOnly as PriceBuyOnly,
    ei.ItemCount as ItemCount,

    ifnull(MAX(cb.Bid),0) as BestPrice,
    count(cb.ItemIdn) as CountBids

FROM items ei
LEFT JOIN CountBids cb ON cb.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

WHERE ei.User = '0' 
GROUP BY ei.ItemIdn
Order by ei.DateStart ASC 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

UPDATE:

When joining with multiple tables, and needing to group each one, you need to use subqueries. Each subquery needs to do its own grouping, you don't use aggregation in the main query.

```
SELECT 
    ei.ItemIdn as ItemIdn,
    ei.UserIdn as UserIdn,
    ifnull(cb.BestPrice,0) as BestPrice,
    cv.CountShow as CountShow,
    cb.CountBids as CountBids,
    ifnull(r.CountReactivation,0) as CountReactivation

FROM items ei

    left join (
      SELECT count(*) as CountShow, ItemIdn 
      FROM CountViewes 
      GROUP BY ItemIdn) as cv on cv.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

    left join (
      SELECT count(*) as CountBids, Max(Bid) as BestPrice, ItemIdn 
      FROM CountBids 
      GROUP BY ItemIdn) as cb on cb.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

    left join (SELECT count(*) as CountReactivation, ItemIdn 
               FROM Reactivation 
               GROUP BY ItemIdn) as r on r.ItemIdn = ei.ItemIdn

WHERE ei.UserIdn = '0000' 
LIMIT 0, 25
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19/5)

BTW, there's no need to have `WHERE ItemIdn = ItemIdn` in the queries. If there's no condition on the query, just leave out the `WHERE` clause.

Comment: i can not make aright - please see **[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/24d19/3)** P.S.: i edit question.

Comment: When joining with multiple tables that need to be grouped, you have to use subqueries.